# Laravel 9 Unsupported mail transport []

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, laravel-9

I have Unsupported mail transport" error when send an email in laravel 9 project.

Here is my .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER = smtp
MAIL_HOST = smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT = 587
MAIL_USERNAME = *****@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD = *******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION = tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=*****@gmail.com
```

Here is my config/mail.php

```
    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'from' => ['address' => '*****', 'name' => '*****'],
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
            'pretend' => false,
        ],
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Your `driver` key should be `transport` - - `'transport' => 'smtp'`. That should not be pulling from the .env file.  See https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/config/mail.php for what it should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed my config/mail.php like this and it works.

```
'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],
```